# Merging several sentences

Tags: american-english

Situation:
Total 10 samples were parsed.
Error occured while parsing 3 samples.

What i want to tell:
The number of samples which I could not parse.

My try:
Samples Error occured while parsing them? = 3?

I want to place the word 'Samples' in the front.

Comment: What part of learning English are you having trouble with? This website isn't a writing clinic, but if you have a question about a specific aspect of learning English, please edit your question to make it clear, and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: I suggest merging the sentences in your own language and then translating that into English. Clue: you are not going to get anything natural with 'samples' at the front.